# knockout js unable to bind cascading dropdown

Tags: binding, knockout.js, html-select, cascading

I'm new to knockout, and trying to create work out how to populate a second dropdown list based on a selection made in the first.
I've been basing my code on the first [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/35MUY/) provided by rpn in this [conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/knockoutjs/complex%2420viewmodel/knockoutjs/PkCErq6eWT0/lJXIPdiH4sEJ).

Here is my markup

```
<div data-bind="visible: selectedDate">
  <span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().logDate : 'unknown'"></span>
</div>
<br />

<div data-bind="visible: selectedDate">
    <select data-bind="options: filenames,
                       optionsText: name
                       value: selectedFiles"
            multiple="true"></select>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
var modelData = {Id:1,
                 DownloadFiles: [
                  {LogDate:"01/12/2012",
                   Filenames: [
                     "File.000", "File.001"]},
                  {LogDate:"02/12/2012",
                   Filenames: [
                     "File.000", "File.001", "File.002"]},
                  {LogDate:"03/12/2012",
                   Filenames: [
                     "File.000", "File.001", "File.002", "File.003"]},
                  {LogDate:"04/12/2012",
                   Filenames: [
                     "File.000", "File.001", "File.002", "File.003"]}
                 ]};

function AvailableDate(date, filenames) {
    var self = this;
    self.logDate = ko.observable(date);
    this.filenames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(filenames || [], function(filename) {
        return new Filename(filename.name);
    }));
}

function Filename(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);    
}
var viewModel = {
    downloadFiles : ko.observableArray(),
    selectedDate : ko.observable(), // Nothing selected by default
    selectedFiles : ko.observableArray() // Nothing selected by default
};

ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelData.DownloadFiles, function(availableDate) {
   viewModel.downloadFiles.push(new AvailableDate(availableDate.LogDate, availableDate.filenames));
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I just cannot see the problem with the binding to the second dropdown.

Comment: There are a lots problems with your current code. I don't have time now to explain all of them. Here is a working JSFiddle where you play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/wgw53/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this nemesv.  There seems to be more to knockout than first seems from the the tutorials ans Steve Sanderson's presentation.

Comment: It would be great if you could create an answer with your learnings and accept it as solution so that other can learn from it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to nemesv for this solution.

Here is the markup:

```
<select data-bind="options: downloadFiles,
                   optionsText: 'logDate', 
                   value: selectedDate, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select Date'"></select>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedDate">
  <span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().logDate : 'unknown'">
  </span>
</div>
<br />

<div data-bind="visible: selectedDate">
  <!-- ko with: selectedDate -->
    <select data-bind="options: filenames,
                       optionsText: 'name',
                       selectedOptions: $root.selectedFiles"
            multiple="true"></select>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedFiles())"></span>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
var modelData = {Id:1,
             DownloadFiles: [
              {LogDate:"01/12/2012",
               Filenames: [
                 "File.000", "File.001"]},
              {LogDate:"02/12/2012",
               Filenames: [
                 "File.000", "File.001", "File.002"]},
              {LogDate:"03/12/2012",
               Filenames: [
                 "File.000", "File.001", "File.002", "File.003"]},
              {LogDate:"04/12/2012",
               Filenames: [
                 "File.000", "File.001", "File.002", "File.003"]}
             ]};


function AvailableDate(date, filenames) {
    var self = this;
    self.logDate = ko.observable(date);
    this.filenames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(filenames || [], function(filename) {
        return new Filename(filename);
    }));
}

function Filename(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);    
}
var viewModel = {
    downloadFiles : ko.observableArray(),
    selectedDate : ko.observable(), // Nothing selected by default
    selectedFiles : ko.observableArray() // Nothing selected by default
};

ko.utils.arrayForEach(modelData.DownloadFiles, function(availableDate) {
   viewModel.downloadFiles.push(new AvailableDate(availableDate.LogDate, availableDate.Filenames));
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And thank you for the prompt delixfe.  I understand why leaving the solution on jsfiddle only is a bad idea.